# How to create maps for the fn key in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I've been having some pains in my left little finger, and I'd like to try to alleviate it's task by using the Fn key in Mac keyboards as the Ctrl key in MacVim, since that's where 90% of my action happens.

I've found how to switch the Ctrl and Fn keys globally in the system, but I'd prefer only for MacVim, or for selective applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MacVim understands the `fn` key. It has "names" for most special keys but not for this one.

If I'm correct you'll need to do that using a [third party app](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25141/keyremap4macbook).